# Why was only Arjuna referred as "Partha", but not Yudhishtira or Bheema?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna

As per [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arjuna), Arjuna was also called '**Partha**' because he was son of Kunti (**Pritha**).

Why could not Yudhishtira/Bheema be called by this name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Sabhaparva of Mahabharta , after Pandavas leave for the forest for exile, this verse appears:

> **वनं गतेषु पार्थेषु निर्जितेषु दुरोदरे ।**
>
> **धृतराष्ट्रं महाराजा तदा चिन्ता समाविशत् ।।** **[Sabhaparva 2-103]**
>
> **Vanam gateshu partheshu nirjiteshu durodare |**
>
> **Dhrtaraashtram mahaaraja tadaa chintaa samaavishat || [Sabhaparva**
>   **2-103]**

The meaning of this verse is: *'O Maharaja, with the Parthas (to be understood as the Pandavas) being defeated at dice and being gone to the forest, anxiety encroached upon Dhritarashtra'*

Thus, the term 'Partha' has been used in Mahabharata to represent "son of 'Pritha'/'Kunti'". Technically it may not fit for Nakula & Sahadeva, as they were biological sons of Madri. But since they were adopted by Kunti with equal love, they can also be referred as 'Partha'. However, it's mostly used for Arjuna.

Comment: Good answer. However, *Partha* shouldn't be used for Nakula and Sahadeva in literal sense but since she adopted them, it can be used. I have edited that part in the answer. If you wish you may remove it.

Comment: @iammilind Thanks for edit ,it's looks more convenience

Comment: Above comment is telling that Nakula and Sahadeva can't be called with the name: Partha. All sons of Kunthi can be called "Parthas". I agree. But why it mostly used only for Arjuna and why not Bheema or Yudistara? Any proper reason?

Comment: @user1389480 Yudhishtira is called Partha many time in Mahabharata. For example, see few initial chapters of Shanti Parva..